# React Native Image url as param

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make a basic React Native app where on the main page a person's picture will be displayed and on clicking that a new View will open and have all the details of that particular person. I'm able to print the name of the person but can't get to display his image, which is saved by the name of the person itself. Example - If the name is XYZ, image name is XYZ.jpg

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, ScrollView, Button, TouchableWithoutFeedback} from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';


class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <ScrollView vertical={true} contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}>
                  <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
                  <TouchableWithoutFeedback  title="Go to Details" onPress={() => {
                        this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {
                        name: 'Rohit',
                        otherParam: 'anything you want here',
                        });
                  }}>
                  <View style={styles.view}>
                      <Image source={require('./assets/rohit.jpg')} style={styles.image}></Image>
                      <Text style={styles.text}>Rohit</Text>
                  </View>
                  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

          </ScrollView>
        </View>
    )
  }
}

class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const name = navigation.getParam('name', 'NO-ID');
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
  ----HERE--->    <Image source={require('./assets/'+{name}+'.jpg')} style={styles.image}></Image>
        <Text>{name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Error]

Comment: remove the brackets around name , this one {}. and try hope it helps. or string concatenate it before. i heard that if you concatenate two strings in react native require it throws error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it states in [Images docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#static-image-resources), you can't use dynamic image path in react-native unless they are network image paths. Local image paths need to be known in compile so dynamic paths are not supported.

> In order for this to work, the image name in require has to be known statically.
>
> ```
> // GOOD
> <Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />;
>
> // BAD
> var icon = this.props.active ? 'my-icon-active' : 'my-icon-inactive';
> <Image source={require('./' + icon + '.png')} />;
>
> // GOOD
> var icon = this.props.active
>   ? require('./my-icon-active.png')
>   : require('./my-icon-inactive.png');
> <Image source={icon} />;
> ```